# Jquery ajax Select Radio, check boxes and drop downs depending on the data retrived from database?

Tags: jquery

I am trying to select Radio, check boxes and drop downs depending on the data retrived from database. So far I have only tried the radio button but haven't got any success, here is what i have.

**edit_cc_form.php**

```
<?php

include("../MySqlConnection.php"); 


        if(isset($_GET['edit']))

        {

            $id = $_GET['edit'];

            $query = "SELECT DesiredEffectiveDate,
                             NameofAssociation,
                             DBA,
                             TaxID,
                             StreetAddress,
                             City,
                             State,
                             Zip,   
                             AssociationContactName,    
                             Telephone,     
                             Email,     
                             CurrentEligibleMembers,    
                             PaymentMethods,    
                             LifeLockBasic,     
                             LifeLockCommandCenter,     
                             LifeLockUltimate,  
                             EsignatureTitle, 
                             Esignature,    
                             DateSigned,    
                             WritingProducer,   
                             WritingProducerCode 
                             FROM Association_Enrollment WHERE id = '$id'";

            $result = mysql_query($query);

            $row = mysql_fetch_row($result);  

            $DesiredEffectiveDate = $row[0];

            $NameofAssociation = $row[1];

            $DBA = $row[2];

            $TaxID = $row[3];

            $StreetAddress = $row[4];

            $City = $row[5];

            $State = $row[6];

            $Zip = $row[7];

            $AssociationContactName = $row[8];

            $Telephone = $row[9];

            $Email = $row[10];

            $CurrentEligibleMembers = $row[11];

            $PaymentMethods = $row[12];

            $LifeLockBasic = $row[13];

            $LifeLockCommandCenter = $row[14];

            $LifeLockUltimate = $row[15];

            $EsignatureTitle = $row[16];

            $Esignature = $row[17];

            $DateSigned = $row[18];


            $WritingProducer = $row[19];

            $WritingProducerCode = $row[20];


            $full = $DesiredEffectiveDate.":".$NameofAssociation.":".$DBA.":".$TaxID.":".$StreetAddress.":".$City.":".$State.":".$Zip.":".$AssociationContactName.":".$Telephone.":".$Email.":".$CurrentEligibleMembers.":".$PaymentMethods.":".$LifeLockBasic.":".$LifeLockCommandCenter.":".$LifeLockUltimate.":".$EsignatureTitle.":".$Esignature.":".$DateSigned.":".$WritingProducer.":".$WritingProducerCode.":".$id;

            echo $full;

        }
```

?>

**Jquery Ajax That handles the data returned**

```
    $('a.edit_cc_form').click(function(){


                                $.ajax({

                                    type: 'get',

                                    url: 'cc_form/edit_cc_form.php',

                                    data: 'ajax=1&edit=' + $(this).attr('id'),

                                    success: function(data){

                                            var temp = data.split(':');

                                             $('#DesiredEffectiveDate').val(temp[0]);

                                             $('#NameofAssociation').val(temp[1]);

                                             $('#DBA').val(temp[2]);

                                             $('#TaxID').val(temp[3]);

                                             $('#StreetAddress').val(temp[4]);

                                             $('#City').val(temp[5]);

                                             $('#State').val(temp[6]);

                                             $('#Zip').val(temp[7]);

                                             $('#AssociationContactName').val(temp[8]);

                                             $('#Telephone').val(temp[9]);

                                             $('#Email').val(temp[10]);

                                             $('#CurrentEligibleMembers').val(temp[11]);



                                             if(temp[12] == 'Deduction handled by Association')
                                                {

                                                    $("input[name='PaymentMethods1']:checked").val();

                                                }


                                            if(temp[12] == 'Direct Bill Members with Credit Card')
                                                {

                                                    $("input[name='PaymentMethods2']:checked").val();

                                                }


                                             $('#LifeLockBasic').val(temp[13]);

                                             $('#LifeLockCommandCenter').val(temp[14]);

                                             $('#LifeLockUltimate').val(temp[15]);

                                             $('#EsignatureTitle').val(temp[16]);

                                             $('#Esignature').val(temp[17]);

                                             $('#DateSigned').val(temp[18]);

                                             $('#WritingProducer').val(temp[19]);

                                             $('#WritingProducerCode').val(temp[20]);

                                             $('#update_cc').val(temp[21]);

                                    }

                                });


                    $("#cc_form").show();

                    $("#user_list_cc").hide();  


        }); // edit CC forms end
```

Part of the form that I am trying to select based on the data stored on temp[12] after parsing the result returned. Any Ideas on how to do this, any help is really appreciated.

```
<td class="section-sub-head">
                                                    <label>Payment Methods:</label>
                                                    <br /><br />

                                                    <input type="radio" name="PaymentMethods1" id="PaymentMethods"  value="Deduction handled by Association" style="width:20px !important;" class="required"/> Deduction handled by Association

                                     <br /> <br />      
                                                <input type="radio" name="PaymentMethods2" id="PaymentMethods"  value="Direct Bill Members with Credit Card"  style="width:20px !important;" class="required" /> Direct Bill Members with Credit Card      
                                                     <br />
                                                        <label for="PaymentMethods" class="error" generated="true"></label>
                                                        <br />
                                                </td>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

-> You need to list of things need to check.

- First put alert in your success function and check it returned data successsfully which you want.
- I checked your html format.It is totally wrong.Id is unique field and you used 2 times.And if payment methods are in group then name field in both radio button are same which is diffrent in your html like PaymentMethods1 and PaymentMethods2.need to correct this.
- In jquery,  $("input[name='PaymentMethods1']:checked").val();
  I don't understand why you put this.it is fetching value and you don't take any variable to take this value.

Comment: I think i fiugred out what was wrong with my code thank you for your help!